Try to test a service by mocking a repository method which requires passing Pageable. The unit test always thows java.lang.NullPointerException
Cannot properly mock the method in repository which requires passing Pageable. I tried everything I could find. PLEASE HELP.
So I cannot mock findAllByTypeContainsAndSexLike method
TEST CLASS:
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AnimalServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private AnimalServiceImpl animalService;
    @Mock
    private AnimalRepository animalRepository;
    @Mock
    private Page<Animal> page;

    @Test
    public void readAnimalsTestWithoutFilteringByCategory() {
        List<Animal> animals = List.of(new Animal(), new Animal());

        when(page.getContent()).thenReturn(animals);
        when(animalRepository.findAllByTypeContainsAndSexLike(anyString(), anyString(), any(PageRequest.class)))
                .thenReturn(new PageImpl<>(animals));

        PaginatedAnimalResponseDTO responseDTO = animalService.readAnimals("", "", "", PageRequest.of(1, 2));
        
        assertEquals(animals.size(), responseDTO.getNumberOfItems());
    }

    @Test
    public void readAnimalsTestWithInvalidSortField() {
        assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> animalService.readAnimals("bird", "", "male",
                        Pageable.unpaged(Sort.by("age"))));
    }
}

Service class:
@Service
public class AnimalServiceImpl implements AnimalService {

    private final AnimalRepository animalRepository;
    private final FileService csvService;
    private final FileService xmlService;

    @Autowired
    public AnimalServiceImpl(AnimalRepository animalRepository,
                             @Qualifier("CSVServiceImpl") FileService csvService,
                             @Qualifier("XMLServiceImpl") FileService xmlService) {
        this.animalRepository = animalRepository;
        this.csvService = csvService;
        this.xmlService = xmlService;
    }

    @Override
    public PaginatedAnimalResponseDTO readAnimals(String type, String category, String sex, Pageable pageable) {
        if(!sortIsValid(pageable.getSort())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid sort field!");
        }

        Page<Animal> animals;

        if(Pattern.matches("[1-4]", category)) {
            animals = animalRepository.findAllByTypeContainsAndCategoryEqualsAndSexLike
                    (type, Integer.parseInt(category), sex + "%", pageable);
        } else {
            animals = animalRepository.findAllByTypeContainsAndSexLike(type, sex + "%", pageable);
        }

        return new PaginatedAnimalResponseDTO(animals.getContent()
                .stream()
                .map(a -> new AnimalDTO(a.getName(), a.getType(), a.getSex(), a.getWeight(), a.getCost(), a.getCategory()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()), animals.getTotalElements(), animals.getTotalPages());

    }

    private boolean sortIsValid(Sort sort) {
        List<String> validSortFields = Arrays.asList("name", "type", "sex", "weight", "cost", "category");

        if(sort != null) {
            for(Sort.Order order : sort) {
                String fieldName = order.getProperty();

                if(!validSortFields.contains(fieldName)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

Repository interface:
@Repository
public interface AnimalRepository extends JpaRepository<Animal, Long> {

    Page<Animal> findAllByTypeContainsAndSexLike(String type, String sex, Pageable pageable);

    Page<Animal> findAllByTypeContainsAndCategoryEqualsAndSexLike(String type, int category, String sex, Pageable pageable);
}

The test method always throws:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.data.domain.Page.getContent()" because "animals" is null

    at com.projects.pumbtesttask.service.impl.AnimalServiceImpl.readAnimals(AnimalServiceImpl.java:57)
    at com.projects.pumbtesttask.service.AnimalServiceTest.readAnimalsTestWithoutFilteringByCategory(AnimalServiceTest.java:38)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

I tried to mock with exactly the same values, with passing different templates and many more

Why do you have @SpringBootTest AND @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)? You are only using mocked fields, so why do you bootstrap the application context?

I cannot reproduce your error (but I get different ones such as unnecessary stubbing).

Your field @Mock page is never used by your tests except for the initial stub. .thenReturn(new PageImpl<>(animals)) returns a real Page instance (which is actually more sensible than stubbing the page).

Please fix your [mre] to actually cause the exception that you mention. (and make sure to include your Java (17+?), JUnit, and Mockito versions in your question)
